# Destructure object in ES2020

Tags: javascript

I have objects converted from JSON responses returned based on some conditions. The nodes of these 2 response objects would be same. but data would be different.How can I refactor and destructure below objects based on conditions?

```
if (searchType === "user") {
  const { user_search, details, education, work } = result?.data;
  search_data = user_search.results || [];
  total = user_search.total || 0;
  personalData = {
    details,
    education,
    work,
  };
}
if (searchType === "admin") {
  const { admin_search, details, education, work } = result?.data;
  search_data = admin_search.results || [];
  total = admin_search.total || 0;
  personalData = {
    details,
    education,
    work,
  };
}
```

Comment: Why not destructure all the properties and then only put the creation of the object inside the if?

Comment: const { user_search, details, education, work } = result?.data;
  const { admin_search, details, education, work } = result?.data;
One is destructured from user_search node and other admin_search node

Comment: It shouldn't matter since a missing property will be undefined and won't throw an error. Then you can use `?.` like elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const { user_search, admin_search, details, education, work } = result?.data;
  const result =  user_search || admin_search || [];
  search_data = result.results; 
  total = result.total || 0;
  personalData = {
    details,
    education,
    work,
  };
```